# Codeigniter Halogy cms installation setup

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system, halogy

i have downloaded a halogy and after extracting i put the extract folder into my htdocs folder in my localhost ..i successfully setup the database but i am getting the error after visiting the url from the browser 
this is the error

```
   Slight problem...

   This domain has not been configured properly.
```

my **folder name** after extracting

```
jesseorndorff-Halogy-35c4050
```

**url**

```
 localhost/jesseorndorff-Halogy-35c4050
```

Comment: ok have you setup the database?

Comment: remove your .htaccess file and try running again

Comment: yeah i have done it ... database is successfully loading.. if there is a problem then it shows me the error because i have checked it already ..so my database is setup successfully

Comment: again the same problem after removing the htaccess file

Comment: The standard installation setup says that put your content in the base directory. It means instead of jesseorndorff-Halogy-35c4050/halogy and jesseorndorff-Halogy-35c4050/system put all content in the localhost

Comment: i didnt get u .. u mean i put halogy and system folder into htdocs folder so my directry structure become like this                         htdocs ->jesseorndorff-Halogy-35c4050,halogy,system .... means 3 folders in htdocs ?

Comment: I have just downloaded the latest version of Halogy and tried to install and encountered same problem as you but i have been using it for two years now. I think there is some problem with latest version

Comment: so what should i do then ? can i find the older versions any on the internet ? or if not then can you send it to me if u still have it ?

Comment: OK i have found a little solution for this i am posting and answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a step by step solution

First rename your folder name with some thing else just for testing.
I changed `jesseorndorff-Halogy-35c4050 to halogy_test`.

Next cut system folder from halogy and paste it in the upper level. Now the structure will be like this.

```
localhost/
    halogy_test/
         halogy/
         system/
         index.php
```

Next go to database.php and set it up.
Next go to `halogy/application/config/config.php` and change
`$config['index_page'] = '';`

to

`$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` on line no 29.

Now go to `application/config/site_config.php` and change

```
$config['staticPath']       =   '/static'
```

to

```
$config['staticPath']       =   '/halogy_test/static';
```

The final step go to `halogy_test/static/js/jquery.flot.init.js` and change

```
'/admin/stats/' to stats/ on line no 2!
```

Done it
Vote up if successfull.

Comment: thanks but now i am getting this error "Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php"  i have followed all your steps

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention this. Go to halogy_test/index.php and paste this line on line no 75. $system_path = 'system';

Comment: error is removed and now the old error come up again                           Slight problem...

This domain has not been configured properly.

Comment: after all this configuretion i am using this link to access and its working fine http://localhost/halogy_test/

Comment: dont know why mine is not working .. i followed all your steps ..can you upload your halogy_test folder to some file sharing website so i can download it or should i upload mine so you can check it where is the problem where i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If you still have this issue after following the answer from @raheel-shan, then you'll want to take a look at the database you're using for your install of Halogy.

There is a table "ha_sites" that stores your sites path in the column "siteDomain". So even if you corrected the path to your site everywhere in your code, you'll still run into issues if the path in "ha_sites.siteDomain" isn't correct.

**To fix this, do one of the following:**

- **(easiest)** Delete all tables, and re-import the sql dump.

or

- Truncate the table "ha_sites".

or

- Fix the path in "ha_sites.siteDomain".