# Template issue - Halogy

Tags: codeigniter, halogy

I have just installed Halogy on my MAMP localhost.  I've followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819687/codeigniter-halogy-cms-installation-setup) to set up all my folders and this is working fine.  Dashboard looks good.  However, my default template is empty. And, no matter what I put in it, after editing and saving - the markup is still empty.  So I cannot get any editable fields in my pages whatsoever. When I edit my page content its just empty. I have also tried creating a new template and applying that to a new page.  Same results.  I am scratching my head here.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what's gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I could help you, since I've been working exclusively with and extending Halogy for about 8 months now. But, I need more details, since this behavior could be attributable to any number of issues. For example, what does the page source look like? Also, please note that, if you're not logged into Halogy, unpublished pages will not appear. However, your default home page should be visible. Have you searched the Halogy forum and/or posted your question there?

Comment: thanks @KenBoyer.  I wasn't sure when you said page source if you meant what was inside the content tab of the page or the actual page source.  there is nothing inside the content tab at all.  But when i did a page view source I noticed the following: <iframe name="preview" id="preview" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>

Comment: and I am logged in.  I have not yet but will check the forum.

Comment: @jco can you post screen shots so we can see exactly how it looks like?